# What does the "R with pencil" icon mean?

Tags: intellij-idea

Yet again JetBrains managed to implement an "ungoogleable" feature.

Does anyone know what this "R with pencil" icon means?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you hover over the icon there is an explanation text:
[image]

which means that this action will run [Rename](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/go/rename-refactorings.html#invoke-rename-refactoring) refactoring for the changed name of the symbol.

See [IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 EAP4: In-place Rename and Change Signature](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/02/intellij-idea-2020-1-eap4/) related blog post about it.

If there are no usages of this variable the Rename action (and icon) is dimmed and a bit different text is displayed (that nothing needs to be updated at this point):
[image]

Comment: I didn't get any tooltip while it was grey. But now it does. Must be a little glitch, otherwise I wouldn't have asked here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the "R" exactly stands for, but it's used to **r**eflect [signature changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/change-signature.html) and so for **r**efactoring methods.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. This icon would offer me to "Rename Usages" after renaming the variable. I figure that where the **R** comes from.

However, in this case, there was no other usage for that variable, therefore the icon was just grey and dead (no tooltip or functionality).